# Python - search a list for items in another list

Tags: python

I have a question which is probably easy, but I can't figure it out. I have a list "l" and I want to find matches from the strings in "q". If I search for one string (as below) it prints all but "the slow brown fox", as expected. I can't figure out how to loop through 'l' searching for elements in 'q'

```
s = '''the quick brown fox
the slow brown fox
the quick red chicken
the quick orange fox'''

l = s.split('\n')

q = ['quick', 'fox']

for i in l:
    if 'quick' in i:
        print(i)
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit: I want to find strings that contain both items in 'q'.

Comment: If your list `q` is bigger, consider using a `set()` instead, as lookup can be done in constant time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for phrase in l:
    if all(word in phrase for word in q):
        print(phrase)
```

Keep in mind that this will match the `quick` in `quickest`, which may or may not be what you want

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention, I need both strings from 'q' to match.

Comment: @kirstyhattersley: sorry, I missed your edit to your post. Check out the edit to my answer

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I thought I'd tried that, but it works perfectly!

Comment: @kirstyhattersley: note that this solution will also match the `quick` in `quickest`. It's [a clXXXic problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem). [This other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35163234/198633) fixes that, though

Answer (score 2):

You can use set operations:

```
>>> set('''the quick brown fox
the slow brown fox
the quick red chicken
the quick orange fox'''.split()).intersection(['quick', 'fox', 'foo'])

{'fox', 'quick'}
```

[update]

> Edit: I want to find strings that contain both items in 'q'.

OK, let me try again. :-)

```
>>> stacks = [_.split() for _ in '''the quick brown fox
the slow brown fox
the quick red chicken
the quick orange fox'''.split('\n')]

>>> needle = ['quick', 'fox']

>>> for stack in stacks:
...     print(stack, set(stack).issuperset(needle))

['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox'] True
['the', 'slow', 'brown', 'fox'] False
['the', 'quick', 'red', 'chicken'] False
['the', 'quick', 'orange', 'fox'] True
```

Comment: Converting the lists to sets and do intersection on it is truly pythonic. Just as get rid of duplicate list items by list(set(<list>)).  Thanks!

Comment: I thought OP wants the lines in which both words in `q` exist.

Comment: @AdamSmith this was not clear for me before she edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

Per your edit, ALL words in `q` must be in the line:

```
filter(lambda ll: all(word in ll for word in q), l)
```

You can also do set operations

```
q_set = set(q)
for ll in l:
    ll_set = set(ll.split())  # each word
    if q_set <= ll_set:
        print(ll)
```

Comment: For the set version, it might be a little bit cleaner to check if q_set is a subset of ll_set, i.e. `if q_set <= ll_set:`.

Comment: Is there any advantage to this code to the (apologies if sounds rude) simpler code from inspectorG4dget below? Or is that how you'd routinely do it?

Comment: @kirstyhattersley The top code block is functionally identical to Gadget's, except that it doesn't print the values, it creates an iterator containing those values. My code is more of a functional style, his is certainly more idiomatic Python. When I wrote my answer, he hadn't seen your edit yet, and I didn't want to snipe the exact layout of his answer just to correct it. `map`, `filter`, and `functools.reduce` are useful tools to learn *in general*, but not incredibly Pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's an over-optimized way:

```
import collections

phrases = collections.defaultdict(list)
for phrase in l:
    for word in phrase.split():
        phrases[word].append(phrase)

for phrase in set.intersection(*[phrases[word] for word in q]):
    print(phrase)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution looks like this:

```
import re

s = '''the quick brown fox
the slow brown fox
the quick red chicken
the quick orange fox'''

l = s.split('\n')

q = ['quick', 'fox']


def match_pattern_list_in_string_list(q, l):
    result = []
    for line in l:
        match = True
        for pattern in q:
            if not re.search(pattern, line):
                match = False
        if match:
            result.append(line)
    return result

print match_pattern_list_in_string_list(q, l)
```

and it returns:

```
['the quick brown fox', 'the quick orange fox']
```